# Replace ending random and add characters with regex

Tags: regex

I've got a list of url with random ending string like this:

```
paris-chambre-double-classique-avec-option-petit-dejeuner-a-lhotel-trianon-rive-gauche-4-pour-2-personnes-8ae0676c-aba2-4cf2-9391-91096a247672

paris-chambre-double-standard-avec-petit-dejeuner-et-acces-spa-pour-2-personnes-a-lhotel-le-mareuil-4-f707b0fe-31cb-4507-b7b3-7b91695bff9c
```

Now I have been trying for the past few days to find a regex to convert this line into :

```
/paris-chambre-double-classique-avec-option-petit-dejeuner-a-lhotel-trianon-rive-gauche-4-pour-2-personnes.html

/paris-chambre-double-standard-avec-petit-dejeuner-et-acces-spa-pour-2-personnes-a-lhotel-le-mareuil-4-f707b0fe-31cb-4507-b7b3-7b91695bff9c.html
```

The problem is the random strings :

```
3d0b087-5701-4199-9d9c-147cca687263
33d0b087-5701-4199-9d9c-147cca687263
```

I need to remove this part without having the last - and add .html:  add a slash before url like that:

I don't want this :

```
/paris-chambre-doubletriplequadruple-confort-avec-petit-dejeuner-a-lhotel-de-france-gare-de-lyon-pour-2-a-4-pers-.html
```

But this :

```
/paris-chambre-doubletriplequadruple-confort-avec-petit-dejeuner-a-lhotel-de-france-gare-de-lyon-pour-2-a-4-pers.html
```

This is for a new Linux server, running MySQL 5, PHP 7 and Apache 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capture in a group what comes before the pattern that you want to match and remove. Then in the replacement use the first capturing group:

```
^(.*)-[a-f0-9]+(?:-[a-f0-9]+){4,5}$
```

That will match:

- `^` Start of string
- `(.*)` Capture in a group matching any char 0+ times
- `-[a-f0-9]+` Match hyphen followed by 1+ times 0-9 or a-f
- `(?:-[a-f0-9]+){4,5}` Repeat 4-5 times matching a hyphen followed by 1+ times 0-9 or a-f
- `$` End of string

Replace with a forward slash and capture group 1 followed by `.html`

```
/$1.html
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SshodR/1) | [php demo](https://3v4l.org/Pqmcd)

For example

```
$strings = [
    "paris-chambre-double-classique-avec-option-petit-dejeuner-a-lhotel-trianon-rive-gauche-4-pour-2-personnes-8ae0676c-aba2-4cf2-9391-91096a247672",
    "paris-chambre-double-standard-avec-petit-dejeuner-et-acces-spa-pour-2-personnes-a-lhotel-le-mareuil-4-f707b0fe-31cb-4507-b7b3-7b91695bff9c"
];

foreach ($strings as $string){
    echo preg_replace('/^(.*)-[a-f0-9]+(?:-[a-f0-9]+){4,5}$/', '/$1.html', $string) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Result:

```
/paris-chambre-double-classique-avec-option-petit-dejeuner-a-lhotel-trianon-rive-gauche-4-pour-2-personnes.html
/paris-chambre-double-standard-avec-petit-dejeuner-et-acces-spa-pour-2-personnes-a-lhotel-le-mareuil-4.html
```

Comment: And if i want that with regex ?

8ae0676c-aba2-4cf2-9391-91096a247672-paris-chambre-double-classique-avec-option-petit-dejeuner-a-lhotel-trianon-rive-gauche-4-pour-2-personnes.html

Result should do :
paris-chambre-doubletriplequadruple-confort-avec-petit-dejeuner-a-lhotel-de-france-gare-de-lyon-pour-2-a-4-pers.html

The string is allways random but it look like that : 
8ae0676c-aba2-4cf2-9391-91096a247672-

Thanks

Comment: @Sébastien You could use this pattern `^[a-f0-9]+(?:-[a-f0-9]+)+-` and replace with an empty string. https://regex101.com/r/X8rNHb/2/ or with a forward slash.

Answer (score 0):

So these strings are all in the same format?

8 - 4 - 4 - 4 - 12 alphanumerical characters

Then the regex for that could be:

```
/-\w{8}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{12}$/
```

(`\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.)

In PHP, you'd do something like this:

```
$input = "paris-chambre-double-classique-avec-option-petit-dejeuner-a-lhotel-trianon-rive-gauche-4-pour-2-personnes-8ae0676c-aba2-4cf2-9391-91096a247672";
$str = preg_replace("/-\w{8}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{12}$/", "$1.html", $input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your comments seem to indicate that the unique identifying substring can be at the start or the end of the string, then I recommend not applying the `.html` to the replacement -- just concatenated/append it to the sanitized string.

Make the leading/trailing hyphen optional for flexibility.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/b3v3v))

```
$strings = [
    "paris-chambre-double-classique-avec-option-petit-dejeuner-a-lhotel-trianon-rive-gauche-4-pour-2-personnes-8ae0676c-aba2-4cf2-9391-91096a247672",
    "f707b0fe-31cb-4507-b7b3-7b91695bff9c-paris-chambre-double-standard-avec-petit-dejeuner-et-acces-spa-pour-2-personnes-a-lhotel-le-mareuil-4"
];

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    echo preg_replace(
             '/-?[a-f\d]{8}-[a-f\d]{4}-[a-f\d]{4}-[a-f\d]{4}-[a-f\d]{12}-?/',
             '',
             $string
         ) . '.html';
    echo "\n---\n";
}
```

Output:

```
paris-chambre-double-classique-avec-option-petit-dejeuner-a-lhotel-trianon-rive-gauche-4-pour-2-personnes.html
---
paris-chambre-double-standard-avec-petit-dejeuner-et-acces-spa-pour-2-personnes-a-lhotel-le-mareuil-4.html
---
```